# Pandas: return multiple column values based on searching the multiple row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume I have a dataframe in Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo'.split(),
                   'B': 'one one two three two two one three'.split(),
                   'C': '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7'.split(), 
                   'D': '0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14'.split()})
```

The dataframe df looks like

```
      A      B  C   D
 0  foo    one  0   0
 1  bar    one  1   2
 2  foo    two  2   4
 3  bar  three  3   6
 4  foo    two  4   8
 5  bar    two  5  10
 6  foo    one  6  12
 7  foo  three  7  14
```

Note that the type of numbers in `C` and `D` columns is `string`.

I'm thinking about two conditions:

(1) Consecutive search

I want to return the `D` values when I'm searching `C=2:5`. If I use `df.loc[df['C'] == '2:5', "D"]`, it returns an error. How can I do this part?

(2) Discrete search

I'd like to return the `D` values when I'm searching `C=0,3,6`. Again, if I use `df.loc[df['C'] == '0,3,6', "D"]`, it returns an error. What should I write this code?

Comment: You shouldn't be using strings to represent numerical values.

Answer (score 1):

**Consecutive Search:**

The consecutive search method for a range of numerical strings can be taken care of by the [isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and [zfill()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) method. The `zfill` method in the below code creates a list containing the range of the numbers:

```
df.D.loc[df.C.isin([str(i).zfill(1) for i in range(2,6)])]
```

**Discrete Search**

The discrete searching can be done by using the [isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) method:

```
df.D.loc[(df.C.isin(['0','3','6'])]
```

Comment: Yes, for the first case (consecutive searching), we can list them as you wrote. But if they're large interval, say 1:100, we can no longer list them. Is there a more convenient way?

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for this question, and it can be done pretty easily, please chek the edited answer.